# Processing GRIB-2 Data in .Net

Tags: c#, f#, grib

Is there a library for reading GRIB2 data files in .NET (preferably in F#)?

If not, where is a specification that formally defines the GRIB2 data format?

Comment: Ben, please see my profile and send me an e-mail. I too have an interest in processing GRIB in F# and would be interested in starting an open source project with that goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [link to the GRIB2 specification](http://graphical.weather.gov/docs/grib_design.html).

Apparently there is [GribCS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gribcs/), an open source library available on SourceForge that you could use to process GRIB files. The fact that is's written in C# doesn't matter as all .NET languages (including F#) can use it..

Answer (score 1):

[GribApi.NET](https://github.com/0x1mason/GribApi.NET) is now available. It supports reading and writing GRIB 1 and 2 files.

Disclaimer: I am the author (of the C# wrapper, anyway)

Comment: Left you an open issue on GitHub your library is currently no degribbing grib2 files correctly.

Comment: A configuration change has fixed the issue. Excellent work! https://github.com/0x1mason/GribApi.NET/issues/47#issuecomment-292291679